# PHP: $_FILES returns empty

Tags: php, html, file, variables, upload

Pardon if parts of this question don't make sense—I'm a newb to programming in general. Feel free to correct me!

Here's my problem: I'm making a PHP upload page that uses $_POST. There are two upload fields in the HTML section, both of which are optional. So here's my code for, let's say, example-upload.php:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="upload1" name="upload1" accept=".jpg">
    <input type="file" id="upload2" name="upload2" accept=".jpg">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit either, both, or none of these</button>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['upload1'])) {
        $filename_upload1 = $_FILES['upload1']['name'];
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['upload2'])) {
        $filename_upload2 = $_FILES['upload2']['name'];
    }
    // Checks if there is no upload at all
    if (!isset($filename_upload1) && !isset($filename_upload2)) {
        echo 'You didn\'t upload anything and that\'s OK';
    } else {
        if (isset($filename_upload1)) {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload1']['tmp_name'], 'path/to/file/' . $filename_upload1);
        }
        if (isset($filename_upload2)) {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload2']['tmp_name'], 'path/to/file/' . $filename_upload2);
        }
        echo 'One or two files was successfully uploaded';
    }
}
?>
```

Each time I run this, submitting either one or both files, I get the "You didn't upload anything and that's okay" message, leading me to believe that I'm doing something wrong with the $_FILES variable. The unusual thing is that I have a different form on a similar page, except with one upload field instead of two. That seems to work.

Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: we're dealing with files here not $_POST so `if (!empty($_POST['uploadX']))` will fail.

Comment: next time >>> http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and make sure that folder you're wanting to upload to, has the right permissions to write to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `$_POST['upload1']` variable in your form.
Files are passed within `$_FILES` array.

So, in simplest case you can check `$_FILES['upload1']['name']`:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['upload1']['name'])) {
    $filename_upload1 = $_FILES['upload1']['name'];
}
```

And the same check for `upload2`:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['upload2']['name'])) {
    $filename_upload2 = $_FILES['upload2']['name'];
}
```

Comment: you missed one ;-) there's 2.

Comment: That's just an example)

Comment: I like to dot all the `i`'s and bar all the `t`'s - wink. They might think there's only one wrong.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Very obvious problem in retrospect, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to check `$_FILES` and not `$_POST`

```
if (!empty($_FILES['upload1']))
{
    $filename_upload1 = $_FILES['upload1']['name'];
}
```